# Extract two strings from existing one

Tags: java, android, regex, string, substring

I'm trying to create a simple rss reader for Android and it's basically working. The problem is that in order to display the article's content, i use the `<description>` tag from the rss. It appears ok, but there is an `<img>` tag that usually goes off screen because it is bigger.
I used `getSettings()` to **resize** it to fit the screen but that takes a toll to the text's `size` too.

So i want to **extract** the text and the img tag from the description and store them to **two different** strings in order to be able to format them easier. I tried using regular expressions and some java methods that I found but couldn't make it work.

The description tag is formed in this way:

```
 <p style="text-align: justify;"><img src="http://url" alt="something here" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" />a block of text goes here</p>
```

So i want two strings:

```
str1 = <p style="text-align: justify;">a block of text goes here</p>

str2 = <img src="http://url" alt="something here" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" />
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try  this

```
String s1 = s.replaceAll(".+(<img.+?/>).+", "$1");
String s2 = s.replaceAll("(.+)<img.+?/>(.+)", "$1$2");
```

Comment: thanks a lot! exactly what I was asking. String seem to work perfectly and now i can at last use them as i want.